# Angular printing out $scope function instead of returning value (when called from DOM)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api

I'm trying to load an image from Google Drive into an image elemnent in my Angular application:

```
        <div >
            <div ng-repeat="attachment in event.attachments">
                <img src="{{getImage(attachment.fileId)}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The code in my controller:

```
$scope.getImage = function(fileId){
    return 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+fileId;
};
```

When I run the code the request URL show that the function name is being printed out instead of returning the image URL. Here is the request:

> http://localhost:3000/%7B%7BgetImage(attachment.fileId)%7D%7D

Can anyone help me to get the image to load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-src` to wait for the interpolation to take place, like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{getImage(attachment.fileId)}}"/>
```

More on `ng-src` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `ng-src` attribute instead: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc